# Cloudbuild having issue when running the kubelet cloudbuilder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy the new changes to kubernetes cluster using the Google Cloud Provider **CloudBuild**. Whenever I make some changes the trigger is working fine and its starting a new build but here is the issue I am getting with this cloudbuild.yaml.

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  #step1      
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image', '.' ]
  #step 2
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image']
  #step 3 for testing
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['get', 'pods']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cloudbuild-test'
  #STEP-4
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image'
```

Step 1 and 2 are working fine but the issue is with the step3 where for testing purpose I simply ran the ***get pods*** command to test if it will work or not. Here is the issue I am getting in the logs.

```
Running: gcloud container clusters get-credentials --project="journeyfoods-io" --zone="us-central1-a" "cloudbuild-test"
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/XXXX/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/cloudbuild-test".
```

> What permissions is it looking for? Do I need to do some
>   authentication before running the steps or What exactly am I missing?

Comment: I can see that a "-" is missing in your cloudbuild.yaml file in the name of step 3. Is that a typo while you were copying it? If not, please add it.

Comment: @siamsot there is # in the beginning, is a commented line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps of a Cloud Build build are executed using with the `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` service account. From the Cloud Build [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions) about this topic:

> When you enable the Cloud Build API, the service account is
>   automatically created and granted the Cloud Build Service Account role
>   for your project. This role is sufficient for several tasks,
>   including:
>
> - Fetching code from your project's Cloud Source Repository
> - Downloading files from any Cloud Storage bucket owned by your project
> - Saving build logs in Cloud Logging
> - Pushing Docker images to Container Registry
> - Pulling base images from Container Registry

But this service account does not have permissions for certain actions by default ( in particular the `container.clusters.get` permission is not grated by default). So you need to [grant it](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access) with a proper IAM role. In your case the `Kubernetes Engine Developer` role contains the `container.clusters.get` permission as you can see in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#kubernetes-engine-roles).